# Which preposition is proper-in or on, and why?

Tags: prepositions

While writing a case-study, I wrote the following sentence:

> The client wanted live data sync ***in*** a mobile device.

But, Grammarly shows me that 'in' is wrong, I should put 'on' instead.

> The client wanted live data sync ***on*** a mobile device.

I know that some of the active and distinguished members of ELL are not that much satisfied with Grammarly. Therefore, I ask this question.

If Grammarly  is right here, then I would like to know more about using 'in' and 'on' in this context.

Comment: Broadly speaking, "I want X in my mobile device" means you want X physically inside of the device. "I want X on my mobile device" means you want X accessible through your phone, like an app.

Comment: There is no difference at all between the prepositions in this case. One reader or editor will prefer one, and one the other. There is no Great International Authority which can impose an answer; use whichever you like.

Comment: "on a mobile device". It is the same as "on the phone" (not "in the phone").

Comment: Can you provide a link to the grammarly article that suggests that **in** is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

We say "{a capability} **on** {a device}" rather than "{a capability} in {a device}", because "on {a device}" is used when you are are using the device, much like "hand-brakes on a bicycle" and "television on the public transport". This may be a metaphorical extension of "on" denoting "on the surface of". (Note that we say "{a capability} **in/of** {an operating system}" and do not use "on".)

Comment: And see also http://english.stackexchange.com/q/95409/75136 (which is about executing something **on** windows as a **platform**). English prepositions, like in other natural languages, are easier to learn by experience than by explanation. =)